# MongoDb Search in Document's Collection returns only fully matched result - Why?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to locate a user with a Username and a Password that match.
I have an office collection that each office document contains MANY users

```
var builder = Builders<MnOffice>.Filter;

            var filter = builder.AnyEq(o => o.Users, new OfficeUser()
            {
                Username = username,
                Password = password
            });
            var office = await Offices.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return office;
```

the above query returns null. although it should get the result back.
the OfficeUser class has three properties,
Username, Password, and Name.
Mongo forces me that all three properties will match in the query,
all I want is to have 2 properties matching (usename and password) 
in order to get the result back,
How can accomplish that? no good documentation for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var filter = builder.ElemMatch(o => o.Users, user => user.Username == username && user.Password == password);
```

Solved that using ElemMatch, but still dont understand the logic behind the first attempt.

Comment: The difference is that the arguments to [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) are in themselves another "query". That query asks "do these properties match a sub-document within the array". The difference **without** `$elemMatch` is that it is asking "does a subdocument in the array *exactly* match this?", Just like asking fieldA = "b", you are asking arrayC = { "d": "e", "f": g }. Which of course since all elements have more fields than that, there is no match.

Comment: Well, if I wanted the same exact document I had to give that exact model for the query, and then that makes sense, but like LINQ query's and even SQL query's when you search and take out an argument you always under the assumption that this will not be taking into account in the query itself. Its interesting to know what will happen for documents that doesnt have that extra field, will it find those or not?

Comment: What can I say is that this is not LINQ or SQL. And also consider that LINQ was originally designed with SQL mapping in mind.